# next iterator after end() in std::list

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdlist

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <deque>
int main( void )
{
    std::deque< std::deque< int > > integers_lists ;
    const std::list< int > list0 { 1 , 2 , 3 } ;
    for ( auto current = std::next( list0.cbegin() ) 
          ; current != std::next( list0.cend() ) 
          ; ++ current ) integers_lists.emplace_back( list0.cbegin() , current ) ;
    for ( const auto& sub : integers_lists )
    {
        for ( auto each : sub ) std::cout << each << " " ;
        std::cout << "\n" ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

does STL guarantee the correctness of `current != std::next( list0.cend() )` expression in this case.? 
and where exactly that's pointed in Standard.?

Comment: end is the position after the last element, you don't need to next it.

Comment: No. That's the entire point of the `end()` iterator: to *stop* you going past it.

Comment: @GreenTree, this code skips the first element. Is this your intention? You want to use every item *except* the first?

Comment: @Aaron McDaid, I have updated the question.

Comment: Tip if you're using libstdc++: try [`-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/libstdc++/manual/manual/bk01pt03ch17s03.html#debug_mode.using.mode), and you'll get "Error: attempt to increment a past-the-end iterator."

Comment: Based on the latest edits, it appears that you are trying to create a "list-of-lists" containing every sublist of the original list. Is this true? I suggest that you edit your question (or perhaps add a new question) to state this clearly. We can help with that

Comment: @Aaron McDaid, no, that was purely theoretical question. if rbegin returns the end iterator , i have made assumptions, that std::list implemented via sentinel ( for most of implementations ). if loop doesn't change list0, then the next after last must be the first.
but, of course, my thoughts are not compatible with c++ nature.  
Thank you.

Comment: @Aaron McDaid, sorry, not rbegin, i mean rend.

Comment: @GreenTree, `cbegin` or `rbegin`?

Comment: @Aaron McDaid, `prev( begin() ) == end()` for, at least, two implementations. so I began to fantasize.

Comment: @GreenTree, you should have said that at the start. It changes everything about your question. But no, the answer is that the standard doesn't expect that kind of 'circular' implementation of list. And `.end()` iterators are pretty much useless (except to compare to).

Comment: .. and I suggest you forget about complex arbitrary possibilities about how a list iterator might be implement, and instead just focus on clearly describing what you want to do with the list and write a conventional algorithm

Answer (score 4):

`std::next( list0.end() )` is invalid in almost any context.

Even if you simplified your program to this:

```
int main() {
    std::list<int> list0 { 1 , 2 , 3 } ;
    auto iter = std::next(list0.end());
}
```

it would be invalid. You can compare against an `.end()` iterator, but you cannot dereference it and nor can you iterate past it via `std::next`. It's undefined behaviour.

If you want to use each item in the list once, simply do:

```
for(auto & reference_to_current : list0) {
    /* ... */
}
```

or, if you insist on using iterators,

```
for(auto current =  list0.begin()
   ;     current != list0.end()
   ;  ++ current)
{ /* ... */ }
```

And yes, that will include every item, including the last item. The `.end()` iterator is special - it doesn't point to the last item, it points to the next slot just *after* the last item. "one-past-the-end".

Finally, `next(list0.begin())` skips the first item. Are you sure you want to skip the first item?

***Update:*** if you *do* want to skip the first item, but use all other items, you can use

```
if(list0.empty()) {
    /* Error, list must not be empty */
} else {
    for(auto current =  std::next(list0.begin()) // skip first item
       ;     current !=           list0.end()
   ;  ++ current)
    { /* ... */ }
}
```

The `if` is very important, because we must not call `std::next(list0.begin())` if the list is empty.

Comment: Better yet, let `current` go from `list0.begin()` to (and excluding) `list0.end()`, then just use `std::next(current)` inside the loop body. (Note: this assumes cloned iterators can be incremented independently. For the container in the question, this assumption is valid.)

Comment: In that case, @hvd, when `current` is at the final item, `*current` would be valid but `*next(current)` would not. This is because `next(current)== list0.end()` in that case. Have I misunderstood our goal? Is it to iterate over each item except the first?

Comment: Indeed, but in the OP's loop body, `current` is never dereferenced. `current` is only used as the end of a range. This is valid even if `current` is `list0.end()`. The OP's code doesn't entirely match the question.